# Is it possible to raise beams like these?

Tags: support

I'm visiting houses with my partner, who really likes old cottages.

Problem is, there are lots of doorways like this: [image]

Is is possible to make this doorway 'human' sized without the house falling down. Good answers would include links to projects were it has happened and potential estimates of cost. :)

Comment: Is the beam needed? What EXACTLY is it holding up? If it's removed, could you cut a larger door opening?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to literally raise the roof (and build up the walls to support the raised roof), and the cost is generally prohibitive as that's a rather major alteration to the structure. In the specific case of "cottage" it also messes with "what makes a cottage a cottage, as opposed to a house."